# Mysql event is enabled but not working

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

I'm trying to run the mysql event for delete. 
If the `deleted` field in the `blog` table is set to 1 the data fields will be
transferred to the `blog_archive` table.

This is the `blog` table. If the `deleted` is set to 1 again
the data fields will be transferred to the `blog_archive` table

```
id  title   content   deleted   //blog table
-------------------------------
10 | ass  | sdsd    |   1    |
-------------------------------
```

`blog_archive` table...

```
id  title   content    //blog_archive table
--------------------
10 | ass  | sdsd    
--------------------
```

...the `blog table` is now empty

```
id  title   content   deleted   //blog table
-------------------------------
   |      |         |        |
-------------------------------
```

... At first it works fine but after a couple of minutes and after restart the event does not run or work anymore.
I also tried the `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler='ON';` but still it doesn't work.

Here is the mysql code for event

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `archive_blog` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2016-01-05 21:59:39' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN

    INSERT INTO blog_archive(id, title, content) 
    SELECT id, title, content FROM blog WHERE deleted = 1;

    INSERT INTO audit_archive(id, blog_id, changetype, changetime) 
    SELECT audit.id, audit.blog_id, audit.changetype, audit.changetime FROM audit 
    JOIN blog ON audit.blog_id = blog.id WHERE blog.deleted = 1;

    DELETE FROM blog WHERE deleted = 1;

END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

PS: the `audit` table data will also be transferred to the `audit_archive` table when `deleted` is set to 1 in the `blog` table.